# Best Z3 tactics for elementary algebra of fields

Tags: z3

I want to use Z3 to proof validity of statements like this:

```
∀ a b: ℤ, ~ b = 0 -> (a / b) ^ 2. = (a * a) / (b * b)
```

Or in SMT-LIB format:

```
(declare-fun b () Int)
(declare-fun a () Int)
(assert (=> (= b 0) false))
(assert (let ((a!1 (= (^ (/ (to_real a) (to_real b)) 2.0)
              (/ (to_real (* a a)) (to_real (* b b))))))
  (not a!1)))
(check-sat)
```

But I get timeout with the default tactic. I guess Z3 is wasting its time trying to instantiate numbers in order to find a solution. But I'm only interested in `unsat` output since the problem is generalized and a `sat` output doesn't mean anything. What combination of tactics I should use to find validity of simple algebraic statements like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your script, I get `unsat` pretty quickly:

```
$ time z3 a.smt2
unsat
z3 a.smt2  0.17s user 0.01s system 97% cpu 0.191 total
```

Perhaps your z3 is too old? Here's the version I have:

```
$ z3 --version
Z3 version 4.12.0 - 64 bit
```

Try upgrading, I think the latest released version is 4.12.1.

If the issue persists and you have the latest z3, you should report this as a regression at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: Thanks! My version was from 2 years ago. But in general, is an option to tell z3 that I'm only looking for unsat? In order to get faster unknowns or trying tactics needed for unsat first?

Comment: I don’t think such a setting exists, nor it is clear how the solver would put that to great use. You can tell it not to generate models (in which case if you get `sat` you can’t ask for a model). This could save a bit of time since the solver wouldn’t have to do internal bookkeeping, but I’d doubt that it’d be significant enough for you to notice the difference.